# meaning of "is held to"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The view that customer-facing employees have of their organization **is held to** influence the impression that customers form of the organization.

What does the phrase "is held to" mean in this context?

Does it mean "is going to"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The view that customer-facing employees have of their organization is **believed** [by some people] to influence the impression that customers form of the organization.

Held is the past participle of the verb 'hold'. One of the meanings of this verb is to believe an idea or opinion.

> hold  verb
>   to believe an idea or opinion

[Hold (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hold)